# ip6tables snat don't work properly

Tags: iptables, openvpn, nat, ipv6

I got three computers with these names: laptop, vds and home;

vds is openvpn server; home is openvpn client.
and, I got an ipv6 network 2a01:dead:beef::/64 
vds has address `2a01:dead:beef::311` on `tun0` 
home has address `2a01:dead:beef::312` on `tun0` 
laptop has address `2a01:beef:beef::666` on `en3`

I want have an access from laptop to the home via vds, so I did thin on vds: 
On vds I have added an additional address `2a01:dead:beef::2ea` and I've made these iptables rules:

```
ip6tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 2a01:dead:beef::2ea -j DNAT --to-destination 2a01:dead:beef::312
ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 2a01:dead:beef::312 -o tun0 -j SNAT --to-source 2a01:dead:beef::2ea
```

I've altered routes on vds:

```
vds:~/>ip -6 r
2a01:dead:beef::312 dev tun0  metric 1
2a01:dead:beef::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
2a01:dead:beef::/64 dev tun0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
default via 2a01:dead:beef::1 dev eth0  metric 1024
```

and, in openvpn server config I've added

```
push "route-ipv6 2000::/3"
```

so home's `tun0` became a default ipv6 route:

```
home:~/>ip -6 r
2a01:dead:beef::/64 dev tun0  proto kernel  metric 256
2000::/3 dev tun0  metric 1
fe80::/64 dev mlan0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev eth11  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev tun0  proto kernel  metric 256
```

Now, if I ping 2a01:dead:beef::2ea from my laptop, DNAT and SNAT works correclty, and I got the ping:

```
laptop:~/>ping6 2a01:dead:beef::2ea
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) 2a01:beef:beef::666 --> 2a01:dead:beef::2ea
16 bytes from 2a01:dead:beef::2ea, icmp_seq=0 hlim=55 time=108.618 ms
16 bytes from 2a01:dead:beef::2ea, icmp_seq=1 hlim=55 time=108.752 ms
```

But, if I ping my laptop from home I got no ping:

```
home:~/>ping6 2a01:beef:beef::666
PING 2a01:beef:beef::666 (2a01:beef:beef:0:0:0:0:666) 56 data bytes
^C
--- 2a01:beef:beef::666 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6999ms
```

I've launched tcpdump on laptop and this what I see:

```
laptop:~/>sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump -i en3 -n -nn -ttt "ip6[40]=128 or ip6[40]=129"
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on en3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
00:00:00.000000 IP6 2a01:dead:beef::312 > 2a01:beef:beef::666: ICMP6, echo request, seq 1, length 64
00:00:00.000050 IP6 2a01:beef:beef::666 > 2a01:dead:beef::312: ICMP6, echo reply, seq 1, length 64
00:00:00.999054 IP6 2a01:dead:beef::312 > 2a01:beef:beef::666: ICMP6, echo request, seq 2, length 64
00:00:00.000045 IP6 2a01:beef:beef::666 > 2a01:dead:beef::312: ICMP6, echo reply, seq 2, length 64
00:00:00.999858 IP6 2a01:dead:beef::312 > 2a01:beef:beef::666: ICMP6, echo request, seq 3, length 64
00:00:00.000038 IP6 2a01:beef:beef::666 > 2a01:dead:beef::312: ICMP6, echo reply, seq 3, length 64
00:00:00.999968 IP6 2a01:dead:beef::312 > 2a01:beef:beef::666: ICMP6, echo request, seq 4, length 64
00:00:00.000158 IP6 2a01:beef:beef::666 > 2a01:dead:beef::312: ICMP6, echo reply, seq 4, length 64
```

So, echo requests are coming from `2a01:dead:beef::312` instad of `2a01:dead:beef::2ea`, that means, SNAT don't alter source address this time.

Guys, could you please tell me, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got messed up with out with SNAT rule here. 
Correct rule is

```
ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 2a01:230:2:6::312 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 2a01:230:2:6::2ea
```

I changed outgoing interface from `tun0` to `eth0` because I want to match packets going outside, not inside.

I still pretty confused, how this could half-work, please impove this answer, if you know how.